# How to create a sharepoint web site

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I saw that it's  possible to share an Access database on sharepoint So I want to know the process to do so!

Comment: http://lmgtfy.com/?q=sharepoint+share+access+database

Answer (score 0):

Access offers various points of integration with Windows SharePoint Services. You can benefit from centrally located data, and can also use SharePoint features to help manage application access and to make data available via a Web browser. For an overview of SharePoint integration, see the article [Introduction to integrating data between Access and a SharePoint site.](https://support.office.com/en-za/article/Introduction-to-integrating-data-between-Access-and-a-SharePoint-site-6fdd36fa-e098-44eb-8c38-9efca5b40206)

To share a database by using SharePoint, you can either **publish your database**, or you can **move your tables to SharePoint lists and then link to them from your Access database**.

Check more over here: [Ways to share an Access database](https://support.office.com/en-za/article/Ways-to-share-an-Access-database-2c24eb08-bee1-453e-be8e-455f847c5c74)

[Build and publish an Access database to SharePoint](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Build-and-publish-an-Access-database-to-SharePoint-E68BF007-410C-43B2-BF21-322DDBCF5411)